# setTimeout timing is off on the first .each() element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue trying to get the timing consistent with the following code. Basically as soon as the page is loaded it should immediately start looping through the `li` elements and highlighting them, removing the previously highlighted element. It works for the most part but the very first element seems to take about twice as long before it starts looping and then the rest seem to be perfectly timed. I have included a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gzhLqzz/2/)

This is the code I am using to loop

```
function addColorClass(boom) {
    $(boom).addClass('li-color');

    if($(boom).is(':last-child')) {
        $(boom).prev().removeClass('li-color');
        setTimeout(function() { cycleFeatures(); $(boom).removeClass('li-color'); }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(boom).prev().removeClass('li-color');
    }

}

function cycleFeatures() {
    i = 1;
    var timer = new Array();
    jQuery('.features').first().addClass('li-color');
    $('.features').each(function($) {
        i++;
        var thiz = this;
        timer[i] = setTimeout(function() { addColorClass(thiz); }, i * 1000);   
    });
}

cycleFeatures();
```

It is an infinite loop so when it reaches the last `li` element it will recall the `cycleFeatures()` function. You can see in the fiddle that the first element seems to stay highlighted about twice as long as all the other elements. I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out, to no avail. Can someone please help me figure out how to keep the highlighted duration consistent.

Comment: You should take advantage of the fact that `.each()` passes your callback both the DOM element *and* it's index. That way you'll have a local variable to use when setting the timeout instead of having all the timeout callbacks share the same (global!!) `i` variable.

Comment: why not use setInterval instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different way to approach the problem that should be easier to understand than your solution, and should work more consistently.

```
var moveLight = function($ele) {
    $(".li-color").removeClass("li-color");
    $ele.addClass("li-color");
};

var idx = 0;
var loop = function() {
    $loopEles = $("li");
    moveLight($loopEles.eq(idx));
    idx = (idx + 1) % $loopEles.length;

    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}

loop();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gzhLqzz/6/

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() function is put in a queue even when it needs to execute after 0 ms. Once the regular flow is completed then the browser starts executing the queue from setTimeout

line 1

setTimeout(0)

line 2

setTimeout(20)

the execution series would be

line 1
line 2
settimeout(0)
settimeout(20)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialize `i` to `1`. The loop increments `i`, so the first timeout is 2 seconds, the next one is 3 seconds, and so on. So there's a 2 second delay the first time.

Simply change it to

```
var i = 0;
```

You should also use the `var` keyword to make it a local variable. It doesn't need to be global.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6gzhLqzz/4/)

Comment: The fiddle you shared is doing the exact same thing it was in my fiddle. If you look at what user:`mash` fiddle acts like that is exactly what I want, although pretty much none of the code is what I initially started with.

Comment: I thought your problem was that when the page is first loaded, it takes 2 seconds for the first cycle. My version only takes 1 second for the first cycle.

Comment: Is your actual problem with what happens when it loops back to the top? That's because you use `setTimeout` to call `cycleFeatures()` again. That waits a second, and then `cycleFeatures` adds a 1-second timeout before the first cycle.

Comment: You misunderstood then, basically I just wanted the amount of time each `li` element was highlighted to be identical

Comment: it was the initial and after it loops back to the top. The top `li` element always stays highlighted twice as long as any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

You have set setTimeout twice and that might be one of the reasons for this.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gzhLqzz/7/

```js
function cycleAll(active) {
    if ( !active ) active = 0;
    var total = jQuery(".list2 .features").length;
    setTimeout(function(){
        prev = active - 1;
        if ( prev < 0 ) prev = total-1;
        jQuery(".features").eq(prev).removeClass("li-color");
        jQuery(".features").eq(active).addClass("li-color");
        active++;
        if ( active >= total ) {
            active = 0;
        };
        cycleAll(active);
    },1000);
}

cycleAll();
```